# Vuejs unable to access dom element after mounted() even with this.nextTick. Using chartjs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is my child element

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <bar-chart :v-if="this.barChartReadyToBeRendered" :chart-data='null' :height="340"></bar-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col-docs col-lg-3">
      <div class="column" style="height: 150px">
        <div class="col">
            <q-select dark stack-label="Show Targets" class="select-notification"
              v-model="selectTargetNotification"
              :options="this.getTargetChangeOptions"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <q-select dark stack-label="Agency" class="select-notification"
              v-model="selectOrgNotification"
              :options="this.getOrganisationOptions"
            />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BarChart from '../../components/BarChart'

export default {
  components: {
    BarChart
  },

.
.
/* Other code */

mounted () {
    console.log('OUTSIDE MOUNTED')
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.$el)
      let ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart')
      console.log('WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW')
      console.log(ctx)
      console.log(this.$el)
      this.createChart('bar-chart')
    })
  }

</script>
```

The bar chart chartjs is

```
<script>
import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

In my parent element, the template is

```
<template>
  <q-page padding class="row justify-center">
    <div style="width: 80vw; max-width: 100vw;">
      <div class="flex-row-docs">
        <div class="doc-container">
          <q-list no-border>
            <div class="row justify-start">
              <div class="col-6">
                <target-changes-agency></target-changes-agency>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="q-mb-md q-mt-md q-headline">Full coverage</div>
            <span v-if="!isNewsByIdLoaded" class="row justify-center">
              <q-spinner-mat :size="36" style="color: #027be3ff; text-align: justify; margin: 2rem;" />
            </span>
            <div class="row">
              <article-cluster :isNewsByIdLoaded="isNewsByIdLoaded"></article-cluster>
            </div>
          </q-list>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

I am expecting to console.log(ctx) and console.log(this.$el), however the output of those 2 is `null` and `<!-- -->` respectively.

I thought mounted and this.$nextTick() will allow me to have access to the DOM. What am i missing here? please help thank you

Comment: Don't use HTML elements IDs, use Vue's `ref` instead. `<bar-chart ref="barChart" ...` in your template and `this.$refs.barChart` in your mounted method.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assuming that `document.getElementById('bar-chart')` would return any element? There is no element with that ID being created. What you're rather looking for is `document.getElementsByTagName('bar-chart')`, but that will also yield no result, because Vue does not internally create [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), but inserts the component's root element in place instead. So, what you can do is give your `bar-chart` component an `id` attribute, which will be passed to the root element automatically.

The next issue is that your `bar-chart` component is only visible when the condition in `v-if` is truthy. That's probably not the case when the component is first being loaded. In this working minimal example, I simply set `v-if="false"`.

```js
const { Bar, mixins } = VueChartJs
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

const BarChart = Vue.component('bar-chart', {
  extends: Bar,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    //this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options) 
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log('mounted bar-chart component:');
        console.log(this.$el)
    });
  }
});

Vue.component('example-component', {
  template: `<div><bar-chart v-if="false" id="barchart" chart-data="null" height="340"></bar-chart></div>`,
  components: [BarChart],
  mounted () {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log('mounted child component:');
        let ctx = document.getElementById('barchart')
        console.log(ctx)
        console.log(this.$el)
      })
    }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs@3.5.0/dist/vue-chartjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <example-component></example-component>
</div>
```

(The stack snippet console actually hides the `<!-- -->`, but you can see it in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/VwwyaJz?editors=1111). Vue automatically inserts this empty HTML comment as a placeholder for a component that is not currently being displayed.)

The output is actually expected, as the `bar-chart` component is not being rendered, therefore `this.$el` (referring to the child component, not the `bar-chart` component) is empty.

Now here ist the same snippet with `v-if="true"` on the `bar-chart` component:

```js
const { Bar, mixins } = VueChartJs
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

const BarChart = Vue.component('bar-chart', {
  extends: Bar,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    //this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options) 
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log('mounted bar-chart component:');
        console.log(this.$el)
    });
  }
});

Vue.component('example-component', {
  template: `<div><bar-chart v-if="true" id="barchart" chart-data="null" height="340"></bar-chart></div>`,
  components: [BarChart],
  mounted () {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log('mounted child component:');
        let ctx = document.getElementById('barchart')
        console.log(ctx)
        console.log(this.$el)
      })
    }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs@3.5.0/dist/vue-chartjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <example-component></example-component>
</div>
```

As you can see, the logs now return the correct elements, also in the `mounted()` hook of the `bar-chart` component.

Of course, you shouldn't use the `id` attribute in your component if you ever plan to have multiple instances of this component, because it would result in multiple elements having the same ID, which is invalid HTML and might lead to unexpected interferences. So, this was only for demonstration purposes in this minimal example. In your real code, you could use [Vue's `ref` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) instead, which you can then refer to via [`this.$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs) inside the parent component.

*There are two other issues in your code:*

1. You don't need the colon in front of `v-if`, because it automatically binds to the expression given as its value.
2. You don't need `this.` in your expressions, you're in the components context automatically and can simply use the properties' names directly.